# Using UIScrollView to scroll both TableView and Main Stack

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, tableview

hope everyone is having a great day.

In my ProfileViewController i have 3 views, one that holds the profile information (like photo, full name), then another that has a button, and the last that holds a tableView. All these are in a Main Stack. How can i implement a UIScrollView , that scrolls everything simultaneously ?

I have searched around but could not find something that would work for me.

[image: this is my viewController]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in wrong direction!!

What you need to do is

1. Remove `Main`(StackView) and add one Single `UITableView` Or `UICollectionView`
2. Create Two different Cell(`UICollectionViewCell` or `UITableViewCell`) one for Profile Header and another for podcast and register it with table or collection view
3. in delegate return `2` for numberOfSection(_:) method and in dequeueReuseableCell method check section and return appropriate cell.